# Getting 400 types.DepositStateRequest on AxelarTest Api

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, axelar

I am looking through the docs and trying to put together an idea of how to track a deposit. If I was to generate a deposit address for a transfer, and hand that off to the user to make the transfer, what is the best way to then watch for the transfer to be completed to the recipient address?

I was thinking that maybe `https://lcd-axelar-testnet.imperator.co/static/swagger/#/QueryService/DepositState` would be a good way for that, but when sending a request like:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://axelartest-lcd.quickapi.com/axelar/evm/v1beta1/deposit_state?params.burnerAddress=0xC54a0134fc0e7e35280692Ba98FdB507Fe4E713A&params.tx_id=0xbdb63b55a92e14aa54273e1564eba1c5b1375605732238e8d5f60f54929fa43c&chain=ethereum-2'
```

I have been getting a 400 back:

```
{
  "code": 3,
  "message": "unexpected type types.Address in *types.DepositStateRequest",
  "details": []
}
```

Hoping for a way that would allow us to not need to watch every source network separately for the transaction to hit the deposit address to be able to query if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the error you're encountering with the DepositState endpoint, it seems like there might be an issue with the request parameters or the types of parameters.

If you try out the `searchTransfers` query from the Axelarscan api, that should offer what you're looking for

See more here: https://docs.axelarscan.io/interchain/searchTransfers